# React Native - Whatsapp like animation not working

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve an animation like whatsapp when you start scrolling the toolbar is hidden and list takes it's space then when scroll back up it is shown again but it's not working out for me so far this is what i got.

**Result**

[image]

**Code**

```
<Animated.View
    style={{
        height: this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 0.55, 1],
            outputRange: [102, 102, 0],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
        }),
        backgroundColor: '#528eff',
        flex: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', fontSize: 14, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.87)'}}>Requests</Text>
        <Text
            style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', fontSize: 36, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.87)'}}>{this.state.information.requests}</Text>
        <View
            style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, bottom: 50, right: 0, width: 2, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.54)'}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', fontSize: 14, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.87)'}}>Total
            value</Text>
        <Text
            numberOfLines={1}
            ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
            style={{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', fontSize: 36, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.87)'}}>{this.state.information.total}</Text>
        <View
            style={{position: 'absolute', top: 50, bottom: 50, right: 0, width: 2, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.54)'}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', fontSize: 14, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.87)'}}>From
            (People)</Text>
        <Text
            style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', fontSize: 36, color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.87)'}}>{this.state.information.people}</Text>
    </View>
</Animated.View>
<ListView
    contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 78}}
    style={{height: this.windowHeight - 183}}
    dataSource={this.state.expensesList}
    scrollEventThrottle={1}
    onScroll={
        Animated.event([{
            nativeEvent: {
                contentOffset: {
                    y: this.state.scrollY
                }
            }
        }])
    }
    enableEmptySections={true}
    renderRow={(rowData) => this._renderRow(rowData)}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer from this Example here:

https://medium.com/@janicduplessis/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e#.dqq02kk49

push up scrollEventThrottle={1} to  scrollEventThrottle={16} for smooth animation.

Comment: Awesome this really helped me a lot, Thanks @VKRM

Comment: :) @BeyondProgramming